# Smooth drawing with QPainter

Tags: c++, qt, animation

How can I smoothly grow an angle/length-changing Arc with Qt QPainter?  Here is minimum code I just created from Qt's [Analog Clock Window Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtgui-analogclock-example.html).

The code randomly changes `m_value` +- 5 in 50-millisecond. This is to simulate the actual behavior I want to achieve. The arc starts at 12 O'clock position and grow counter-clockwise. `m_value` is scaled to fit 360 degree (12 O'clock to 12 O'clock).

My goal is to smoothly change the length of arc, in real-time, in response to the (simulated) value given, regardless of input value jitters.

I want to accomplish 2 things:

1. Smooth redraw of the arc.  The current code directly redraw the
   value at the time.  I does not even use sub angle value.  The result
   is visually noisy at the end of the arc.
2. Update the drawing in along with V-Sync.  So that I don't waste
   computation power for non-displayed redraw.  I don't know how to
   trigger `render` event by V-Sync, so I've setup 33-millisecond
   timer.  This is needed when `m_value` changes in less than 30 msec.

What I don't want

- QtQuick.  I'm looking for QPainter way to do it.

Platform I'm using:

- Qt 5.x
- on Debian Linux (If it matters)

---

```
#include <QtGui>

#include "rasterwindow.h"

class SmoothArc : public RasterWindow
{
public:
    SmoothArc();

protected:
    void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    void render(QPainter *p) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;

private:
    int m_timerId;
    int m_valueTimerId;
    int m_value = 50;
};

SmoothArc::SmoothArc()
{
    setTitle("Smooth Arc");
    resize(200, 200);

    m_timerId = startTimer(33);
    m_valueTimerId = startTimer(100);
}

void SmoothArc::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event)
{
    if (event->timerId() == m_timerId)
        renderLater();
    if (event->timerId() == m_valueTimerId) {
        m_value = m_value + (qrand() % 11 - 5);
        if (m_value > 100) m_value = 100;
        if (m_value < 0) m_value = 0;
    }
}

void SmoothArc::render(QPainter *p)
{
    p->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    int side = qMin(width(), height());
    p->scale(side / 200.0, side / 200.0);

    QRectF rect(10, 10, 180, 180);
    QPen pen = p->pen();
    pen.setWidth(10);
    p->setPen(pen);
    p->drawArc(rect, 90*16, (360*(m_value/100.0))*16);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    SmoothArc arc;
    arc.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Complete code is at https://github.com/yashi/smooth-arc. Usual build process like the following should work.

```sh
git clone https://github.com/yashi/smooth-arc.git
cd smooth-arc
qmake
make
./smooth-arc
```

Comment: Would be a great question, if we could actually compile the code. :)

Comment: If that helps: https://github.com/yashi/smooth-arc . Usual `git clone https://github.com/yashi/smooth-arc.git; cd smooth-arc; qmake; make; ./smooth-arc` should work

Comment: I want to simulate actual input data stream which comes from outside of the program.  And it was easily done by `qrand()`.  No special meaning.  My goal is to smoothly change the length of arc, in real-time, in response to the current value given, regardless of input value jitters.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is it necessary to use `RasterWindow`?

Comment: No. It was taken from a sample I found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the Qt Gui-only approach to this problem, so I'll show how to do it with Qt Widgets instead.

> 1. Smooth redraw of the arc. The current code directly redraw the value at the time. I does not even use sub angle value. The result is visually noisy at the end of the arc.

You can use Qt's [animation framework](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/animation-overview.html) to interpolate property changes:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class SmoothArc : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(qreal value READ value WRITE setValue NOTIFY valueChanged)

public:
    SmoothArc();

    qreal value() const;
    void setValue(qreal value);

signals:
    void valueChanged();

protected:
    void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;

private:
    int m_valueTimerId;
    qreal m_value;
    QPropertyAnimation m_animation;
};

SmoothArc::SmoothArc()
{
    resize(200, 200);

    m_valueTimerId = startTimer(100);
    m_value = 50;
    m_animation.setTargetObject(this);
    m_animation.setPropertyName("value");
}

qreal SmoothArc::value() const
{
    return m_value;
}

void SmoothArc::setValue(qreal value)
{
    if (qFuzzyCompare(value, m_value))
        return;

    m_value = value;
    update();
    emit valueChanged();
}

void SmoothArc::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event)
{
    if (event->timerId() == m_valueTimerId) {
        qreal newValue = m_value + (qrand() % 11 - 5);
        if (newValue > 100) newValue = 100;
        if (newValue < 0) newValue = 0;

        if (m_animation.state() == QPropertyAnimation::Running)
            m_animation.stop();
        m_animation.setStartValue(m_value);
        m_animation.setEndValue(newValue);
        m_animation.start();
    }
}

void SmoothArc::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QPainter p(this);
    p.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    int side = qMin(width(), height());
    p.scale(side / 200.0, side / 200.0);

    QRectF rect(10, 10, 180, 180);
    QPen pen = p.pen();
    pen.setWidth(10);
    p.setPen(pen);
    p.drawArc(rect, 90*16, (360*(m_value/100.0))*16);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    SmoothArc arc;
    arc.show();
    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

[image: arc animation gif]

> 2. Update the drawing in along with V-Sync. So that I don't waste computation power for non-displayed redraw. I don't know how to trigger render event by V-Sync, so I've setup 33-millisecond timer. This is needed when m_value changes in less than 30 msec.

I think that Qt should handle this for you if you use [`update()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#update):

> Updates the widget unless updates are disabled or the widget is hidden.
>
> This function does not cause an immediate repaint; instead it schedules a paint event for processing when Qt returns to the main event loop. This permits Qt to optimize for more speed and less flicker than a call to repaint() does.
>
> Calling update() several times normally results in just one paintEvent() call.

Comment: This is great! Thanks

Comment: I'm slowly learning the animation framework and notice that a few thing I don't understand.  Basically, what the animation framework does is to call property setter (`setValue` in this case) with a interpolated value via a global timer, right? If so, do I need to emit `valueChanged` in `setValue`, since we already call `update` in it, `paintEvent` should be triggered in the next iteration?

Comment: Emission of the change signal _is_ necessary for [some methods](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html#behavior-animations) of declaring animations in QML. However, I can verify that commenting out it won't affect animations declared in C++.